# Is every open set a union of (any number of) sets that are homeomorphic to the entire space?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

For what spaces can we say that every open set is a union of (any number of) (not necessarily disjoint) sets that are homeomorphic to the entire space?

In $\mathbb{R}$ it's true (even with a countable number of open intervals, and with disjoint unions - but I don't care for these conditions in this question). I think that in $\mathbb{R}^n$ it's also possible with open balls. What about in a metric space, or even a topological space?

I think I need to exclude finite spaces because for them a subspace won't be homeomorphic to the whole space because of different cardinality.

Comment: In any normed linear space open balls are homeomorphic to the whole space and any open set is a union of open balls.

Comment: In any infinite cofinite space, a non-empty open set is homeomorphic to the whole space.

Comment: You need to exclude closed surfaces, like spheres or tori, because there the only subset homeomorphic to the whole space is the whole space.  Similarly for higher-dimensional closed manifolds (and also lower-dimensional --- the circle needs to be excluded).

Comment: @AndreasBlass oh, that's the counterexample I was missing .... thanks!

Comment: No proper open subset of $[0,1]$ is homeomorphic to $[0,1]$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy but an open interval can be written as an infinite union of closed intervals.

Comment: @ Dan I agree. I misread the statement.